# Getting Started

Tags: system-installation

Since my Vista is no longer being supported, I want to replace it with Ubuntu.  I had it once before on a different computer, but I'm not sure how to install Ubuntu without deleting my current Operating System. I use my desktop a lot but am not a technician.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely possible to install Ubuntu in a "side-by-side" mode when installing. Because you're installing the desktop version of Ubuntu (just guessing here) you will be prompted during the installation as to how you would like to install Ubuntu. One of the options available will be to installing it along side Vista (if its not listed click more options). After you get past that window it will take you to a window that looks like this:

[image: Ubuntu installation along side Windows]

With the top saying Vista instead of windows 7. Here you can select how much space you would like Windows Vista to have and how much you would like Ubuntu to have. From here you can just continue the installation like normal. On your next boot it will prompt you for which operating system you would like to boot into (and it should do this everytime).

Note: The following instructions are if you have one hard drive/SSD only. If you have multiple and you'd like to install Ubuntu on one of them and keep windows on the other then that is a different set of directions.